# Notation: Concatenate two functions (piecewise) / Concatenate two vectors, lists or tuples

Tags: functions, notation

### Functions

Given two functions $f: F\rightarrow F'$ and $g: G\rightarrow G'$ with disjount domains ($G\cap F=\emptyset$), what are common ways to denote the following function

$ h: F \cup G \rightarrow F' \cup G'$

$ h(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}f(x)&x\in F\\g(x)&x\in G\end{array} \right. $

Maybe, $h=g||f$ ?

### Vectors / Tuples / Lists

Given $x=(a_1,\dots,a_m)$ and $y=(a_{m+1},\dots,a_n)$, is there a standard notation for

$z=(a_1,\dots,a_n)$

Again, what about $z=x||y$?

Comment: At least wikipedia [includes $||$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation_%28mathematics%29#Vector_extension) (w/o any references and I haven't ever seen this notation anywhere in the literature, plus it's arguably not much needed, since there are better alternatives).

Answer (score 3):

for Functions:

Wikipedia calls it an override or overriding union and uses

$ h=f\oplus g$

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overriding_(mathematics)#Restrictions_and_extensions

Comment: This does answer the question, but there is one detail worth emphasizing. The OP asks for the case of disjoint domains, which is a special case of overriding union. However the name "overriding" refers to the precedence that the function $g$ takes over function $f$, over the intersection of their domains. This brakes the symmetry, rendering the operator non-commutative, so care is needed in case $f$ and $g$ have a non-empty domain intersection and each restricted to this intersection yields a different function (i.e., there exists at least one common point mapped to a different value by each.

Comment: Good point. Unrelated to the question: it turned out however, that it is exactly that -- overriding one function with another -- what the OP was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you take the set-theoretic view of functions as sets of ordered pairs, the function defined on the union is literally just the union of the functions.

The tendency to have a notion of codomain of a function that is distinct from its image means this view is perhaps not pedantically correct, but it is nevertheless fairly clear (at least to set theorists) what you mean when you write $f \cup g$.

(I can't necessarily vouch that anyone actually does this, mind!)

Answer (score 1):

For vectors, one would write

$$\mathbf{z} = [\mathbf{x}\ \mathbf{y}]$$

or

$$\mathbf{z} = \begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{x} \\ \mathbf{y}\end{pmatrix}$$

depending on whether the vectors are row/column vectors. You don't often see this, because concatenating the vectors in this way doesn't necessarily take the properties of the vector spaces to which $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ belong and carry them over to the vector space to which $\mathbf{z}$ belongs.

However, this notation is common when describing, for instance, numerical algorithms, etc. It's common in engineering, where one creates state space models in this form. For example, one might write a structural dynamics controllability model as:

$$\frac{d}{dt}\begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{x}(t) \\ \dot{\mathbf{x}}(t) \\ \mathbf{\lambda}(t) \end{pmatrix} = A\begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{x}(t) \\ \dot{\mathbf{x}}(t) \\ \mathbf{\lambda}(t) \end{pmatrix} + B\mathbf{u}(t).$$

Note, however, that "stacking" the vectors doesn't really mean anything mathematically; it's just a notational shortcut.

Comment: I do not think this actually applies to my case, as $((x,y),(z))$ is not in general the same as $(x,y,z)$.

Comment: @user4514 I was referring specifically to your situation of $\mathbf{z} = ( a_1, \ldots, a_m, a_{m+1}, \ldots, a_n )$ being the concatenation of $\mathbf{x} = (a_1, \ldots, a_m)$ and $\mathbf{y} = (a_{m+1}, \ldots, a_n)$.

Comment: If your concatenation is something different, then you basically have some ad-hoc operation, and hence there is no standard notation.

Comment: No, to concatenate two lists is not the same as buidling a nested list. This is always true. I was just trying to explain, that I do not need nesting, I need actual concatenation. Which is amoung other things assiciative. (A property that nesting lacks: $a||b||c=a||(b||c)$ but $((a,b),c)\neq(a,(b,c))$)

Comment: That's not really what you asked in the "Vectors" section. What you asked for in the vectors section is for the concatenation of two vectors (what you present as $z$ is just $x$ and $y$ concatenated). You said nothing about nested lists, and neither did I.

Comment: @user4514, this *is* the notation for vector concatenation. In linear algebra, $[\mathbf x\ \mathbf y]$ means nothing but the vector $[x_1\ x_2\ \ldots\ x_m\ y_1\ y_2 \ldots y_n]$, because in linear algebra we do not have nested lists.

Comment: @RahulNarain I think you have nested lists (vectors) the moment you put vectors into vectors. It does not make sense to argue, as it's simply a question of definition. Is in the linear algebra you are talking about the following true? $\mathrm{x}=[a\; b]\in R^2, \mathrm{y}=[c] \in R^1, \mathrm{u}=[a]\in R^1, \mathrm{w}=[b\; c]\in R^2 \Rightarrow [x\; y]=[u\; w]$?

Comment: @user4514 Nested lists are quite different from vectors. In a nested list, an atomic element inside the list could be either a list or a singleton (or perhaps equivalently, a list of size 1). But in the case of a nested list, the $i$th element can have dimension not equal to 1, whereas any element in a vector is considered to be a scalar. But yes, in such a case, $[x\ y] = [a\ b\ c] = [u\ w]$.

Comment: @Arkamis So you cannot distinguish between the spaces $( R\times R)\times  R$ and $ R\times( R\times  R)$? I know, that they are related by a bijection, but you say their elements are *equal*, which is too fast, for my taste.

Comment: @user4514 Concatenation does not take vectors in $\Bbb R^m$ and $\Bbb R^n$ and send them to $\Bbb R^m \times \Bbb R^n$. It sends the result to $\Bbb R^{m+n}$. There is no distinction then between $\Bbb R^{(m+n)+p}$ and $\Bbb R^{m+(n+p)}$.

Comment: @Arkamis Ok, I see... What would be the notation for an element of $R^1\times R^2$ that can be build up from $x=[a]\in R^1$ and $y=[b\; c]\in R^2$?

Comment: @user4514 The standard notation for a tuple as an element of the cartesian product of sets is $(a,b) \in U \times V$. So you could just write $(x,y) = ([a],[b\ c])$, but this isn't very common. (On the other hand, if you're talking about a function of two vectors, you might see $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})$ such that $\mathbf{f} : \Bbb R^m \times \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^k$ as a common notation; for instance, it is common in numerical analysis).

Comment: @Arkamis Ok, i give up: $[ [a\;b]\; c]$ is the your standard way to write $[a\;b\;c]$.

Comment: There are several issues with this discussion wrt vector space theory. Besides these, note that the $x(t)$ above is not a function, but a value of function $x$ at $t$, so the notation above means just a vector of 3 (e.g. real) numbers, so its derivative is 0. Instead you would need the notation of a vector containing $\frac{dx}{dt}$, if you would like to define a reasonable notation for a vector function. Using $\frac{dx}{dt}(t)$ instead yields one value mapped to by the vector function when given $t$ as argument.

Comment: The formalization of the objects contrasted in the above discussion is that between a [direct sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum) and an (inner) sum. [Naylor & Sell](http://www.amazon.com/Operator-Engineering-Science-Mathematical-Sciences/dp/038795001X) is an excellent reference on this, namely Sec. 4.10, 2.17, 5.20, also 4.8 for what matrix notation stands for.

Comment: See also [direct product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product) and [Hilbert space direct sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space#Direct_sums). Wikipedia appears to call the "inner" of [Naylor & Sell](http://www.amazon.com/Operator-Engineering-Science-Mathematical-Sciences/dp/038795001X) as ["internal direct product"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_direct_product#Internal_and_external_direct_product) and what N&S call plainly "direct" as "external direct product".